# AccountNumber not being updated through Apex data loader. Any suggestions?

Tags: data-loader, account

I have tried to update Accoutnumber with empty value in Account object using Apex Data loader. However, all the fields got updated except this one. Any suggestions. Am i missing something. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Salesforce web services do not set "null" as value for fields. To set a null (or blank) value for a field via dataloader, you need to enable "Insert Null Value" option in Settings. Steps below:-

1. Launch Data Loader
2. Select Settings
3. Check box - Insert Null Values.

For more details refer:- https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005442